# CSS not updating changes with HTML

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

I am attempting to create a website and when I update the CSS it will not show the changes on the site.  I verified file directories, verified all codes are entered correctly via validator program, and even tried to talk with the website hosting company that I go through.  I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.  The site is n1.dandzines.com.

This is the code that I am using for the html document.

```css
html {
  background: #ffffff;
}

#header {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
}

#header img {
  float: left;
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<section id="header" class="header">
  <img src="nflogo.jpeg" alt="logo">
</section>
```

When I originally coded the website the image was 350px x 350px but when i adjusted it to the 175px x 175px it did not change.  Hostgator said it was due to spelling and coding errors, but that is not it.  I use Notepad++ to write the code with and I have never had this issue until recently.

This is all that is in the .htaccess file that Host Gator had in the directory...

```
text/x-generic .htaccess ( UTF-8 Unicode English text )

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I do not know anything about .htaccess files and I am not sure how to edit it if this is wrong.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the page is not cached by pressing Ctrl + R or Ctrl + F5

Comment: Normally I do refresh the screen, but that also seemed to work.  Do you know if that is an issue with all browsers, or is it a FireFox issue...

Comment: What you have in that .htaccess file shouldn't have a bearing on the CSS not displaying. I went to your URL, and saw your stylesheet linking fine, as it should. How are you editing the CSS and HTML? Do you get any error messages when editing/saving the updates? Also, the browser you are using to visit the site shouldn't matter regarding the current code—as long as it's current.

Comment: Sometimes hosting companies have their own cache separate from browser cache. You should go into cPanel or whatever admin you use and search cache. There should be an area where you can clear cache for your website. If you are developing it on your hosting environment, you might want to disable it until you are finished.

Comment: The problem is that the CSS is cached in the browser. You can clear the browser cache or changing the URL/Path of the CSS file, for example, if the path of the CSS file is "css/master.css" you can change it to "css/master.css?v=1.1" this will make the browser think it's a different file that was not been cached and re-render it

Comment: Thank you all.  All of the tips were helpful.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try clearing your cache and then refreshing the page...

not

```
<img src='your image source' alt='logo' height='175' width='175'>
```

after that clean the width and height attributes from the image and try to give it in css file

```
<img src="your image source">


#header img {
   width: 175px;
   height: 175px;
}
```